# Why does MSVC not resolve a call of this->sth to overloaded operator-> correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class LayoutConstraintInfo {
public:
  void print() const {
    std::cout << "Called LayoutConstraintInfo::Print";
  }
};

class LayoutConstraint {
  LayoutConstraintInfo *Ptr;
  LayoutConstraintInfo *operator->() const { return Ptr; }

public:
  void print() const {
    std::cout << "Called LayoutConstraint::Print";
    this->print();
  }
};

int main() {
  LayoutConstraint().print();
  return 0;
}
```

The program crashes with a stack overflow exception (with MSVC 19.00.24215.1).

However, taking a look at this sample, I would expect the following output:

> CalledLayoutConstraint::Print
>
> CalledLayoutConstraintInfo::Print

This is because I expect a call to `this->print()` to call the overloaded  `LayoutConstraintInfo *operator->()` operator.
Therefore, a call to `LayoutConstraint::Print` would call `LayoutConstraintInfo::Print`

I found this porting a Clang project to MSVC: MSVC issued a warning for recursion causing a runtime stack overflow. Clang didn't seem to complain, but I don't have any version of Clang on my Windows PC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I expect a call to `this->print()` to call the overloaded `LayoutConstraintInfo *operator->()` operator.

No. Note that `operator->` is called only with the object of the type of the class itself, not a pointer of it. That means `LayoutConstraint::operator->()` will be used when called with a `LayoutConstraint`, not a `LayoutConstraint *` (e.g. `this`). `this->print()` will always call the member function `LayoutConstraint::print()` directly, which leads to infinite recursion.

You can change it to use with an object of type `LayoutConstraint`, such as `*this`.

```
void print() const {
  std::cout << "Called LayoutConstraint::Print";
  (*this)->print();
}
```

BTW: You can try it with clang [here](http://rextester.com/TJHL74030).